# Extract shortest suffix following a certain character

Tags: bash, sh

I have a string as below which gets added from right side and need to fetch the last words every time I ran in my script automatically.

```
string='apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3'
```

Now I want output as `v3` in this case but I have this string not static it gets always added from right side like:

```
string='apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3 mango:v4 strawberry:v5'
```

Here the output ought to be `v5`.

Now we have cut command in shell where we can fetch as

```
myoutput="(echo "$string" | cut -d ':' -f5)
```

to `v5` do we have any command or argument more where i can use to get the latest added vx details whenever my string gets added with new output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is an alternate option:

```
awk -F: '{ print $NF }' <<< "$string"
```

Set the delimiter to : and then print the last field ($NF)

Comment: Thank you ..that is also one option i explore today .. This also WORKED

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an external utility for that.

```
$ string='apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3'
$ echo "${string##*:}"
v3
$
$ string='apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3 mango:v4 strawberry:v5'
$ echo "${string##*:}"
v5
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

To get the last field, we can reverse the string and pluck out the first field; in my case

```sh
myoutput="$(echo "$string" | rev | cut -d ':' -f1 | rev)"
```

`echo "$myoutput"` will print the extracted field.

Comment: The code you posted had a syntax error which I corrected. The quotes around the command substitution are unnecessary but harmless so I left those in; but they don't really do anything useful. The right-hand side of an assignment is implicitly quoted anyway.

Comment: Hey Triplee thank for your help and effort. have taken the note for it.   THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
$ echo "apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3" | perl -ne ' /.*:(.+)/omg and print $1 '
v3
$ echo 'apple:v1 banana:v3 pineapple:v3 mango:v4 strawberry:v5' | perl -ne ' /.*:(.+)/omg and print $1 '
v5
$
```